# Is there a way to make Google search API to search into my application only?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, google-search-api, personalization

Suppose I am having the application say "Hotel Forest". Can I integrate the Google search API in my asp.net mvc application and If user search for any keyword It should search in "Hotel Forest" only and will provide links / result for "Hotel Forest" only ? In short can we personalize google search for particular  web application / website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inject "inurl:example.com" at the end of the search string and google will only show results from example.com